# Programmatically removing grails artifact from application context

Tags: grails

I recently learned how to register custom grails artifacts (I need it for dynamic controllers in my application) using grailsApplication.addArtefact(java.lang.String artefactType, GrailsClass artefactGrailsClass) and it works fine, but now I realized that I also want to be able to unregister them.

Unfortunately, interface GrailsApplication provides no clear way to do so and it seems that unregistering unwanted dynamically registered grails artifacts can only be done by restarting the whole application.

Maybe I'm missing something and an artifact can be removed from an application without having to restart the app?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can always `rebuild` the `GrailsApplication`. That throws away all artefacts and loads the default ones. That obviously means you'd have to `addArtefact` the artefacts you want to keep again.

Other option is access the `loadedClasses` set (which is protected) and make the changes manually and then call `populateAllClasses` to make available (this method is protected too).

Comment: I'm trying to implement the first approach by collecting all artefacts from `grailsApplication.getAllArtefacts()`, then calling `rebuild` and then adding each collected artefact with `addArtefact`. Unfortunately, it somehow breaks  with apache shiro security filter and my app fails with `javax.servlet.ServletException: Filtered request failed.

 at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:384)`